# Struts2 redirectAction, input & message-store interceptor logic

Tags: struts2

I'm very confused about the redirectAction, input result & message-store interceptor

Suppose we have two actions and both have message-store in their interceptor stack.

**Scenario 1**

```
Form is submitted -> No Errors -> Returns success -> fires a redirectAction -> that action is executed -> fire SUCCESS -> final jsp displayed.
```

This is perfect, and understandable.

**Scenario 2**

```
Form is submitted -> There are errors -> Returns input -> fires a redirectAction -> due to message-store interceptor the errors/messages are found at the second action -> hence, the method shouldn't be executed, instead the errors will be found by an intermediate interceptor and it'll return INPUT
```

Is this flow correct ? Am I missing something ?

But in the 2nd scenario, the form is filled with some values, and I see the 2nd action being executed.

Please correct the flow.

Comment: Yes, it will execute the second action, message store interceptor is for carry forward the messaage or field errors. For reference http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/message-store-interceptor.html

Comment: I tried to test and it didn't executed the 2nd action, in case there were errors sent from the first action. Since some intermediate interceptor returns INPUT result on encountering errors, I forgot it's name.